# How can I add a compiler plugin only to Test in sbt?

Tags: sbt

I have a compiler plugin I've been adding to projects like this in my build.sbt:

```
addCompilerPlugin("co.blocke" %% "dotty-reflection" % "0.2.0")
```

In this case, I don't want the compiler plugin active during main compile, but I DO want it active during test compile.  How can I specify this?

Comment: Did you try this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/62899991/5627026

Comment: Yep, that worked!